# Возможно ли сделать на html/css элемент в виде шестиугольника? Или как правильно сверстать уникальные элементы дизайна в адаптивной вёрстке

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, photoshop

Взял недавно один макет на вёрстку и увидел, что там в дизайне используется шестиугольник, в котором находится текст. Я бы мог просто вырезать этот шестиугольник, но тогда, мне кажется, я просто никак не смогу сделать нормальную адаптивность (для картинки и внутри неё текст), так как там 4 шестиугольника совершенно разных. В общем, вот они:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как было бы правильно такое сверстать?

Answer (score 0):

сверстать можно через псевдо-элементы ::before, ::after + transform: rotate();, но получиться очень грязный код, проще добавить как div с картинкой шестиугольника и в div писать текст